# bindValue does not working with dot PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to use `bindValue` in a query in PHP with PDO, and I can't understand why it doesn't work.

Exemplo:

```
$key = ":where_user_setores.setor_id_0";
$value = 2;

$sth->bindValue($key, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

This way above doesn't work.
The following error is received:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

If I just put the column name directly, it works, example:

```
$key = ":where_setor_id_0";
```

For my code to go live, I had to do an `md5($key)` to ensure that the "dot" would be removed, as this key is only used to be a different identifier in bind.

My indignation is: **WHY DOESN'T IT WORK WHEN WE PUT A "DOT" in the placeholder?**

And if I had two tables with the same columns, wouldn't I be able to use `bindValue`?

I looked in the documentation for something that could explain `":field"`, but there is nothing saying about the limitations of creating these placeholders.

Comment: My simple answer is: A placeholder should be a name only, ANY name. A dot has a special meaning in SQL. Normally your placeholder would simply be something like `:myAlias1`, you shouldn't reference tables in it.

Comment: Why is your bind key an entire SQL expression?

Comment: @Sammitch, because i can have infinity possibilities about fields and values ... this way, i created a function responsible for concat a lot "args", including iterator number to do a difference between the fields.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, I thought the problem wasn't in the SQL. I assumed the problem was occurring during the bindValue process (before the query went to the database). But, the error presented is actually showing SQL code.

Comment: I see you edited your question and it does already look better. Let's not worry about where the bindValue process occurs. It's a fact that things like spaces, dots, semi-columns and reserved words have special meaning in an SQL query. There are [lots of things](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.2/en/language-structure.html) that mean something special. So you can use an underscore, but you cannot use a dot, and there is no compelling reason why you should ever absolutely need a dot in a placeholder.